# Is there a working THREE.js API documentation?

Tags: webgl, three.js

I am trying to learn the basics of THREE.js. I have read a couple of tutorial, and I would like to start experimenting. My problem is that I am not able to find any documentation

[This](http://threejs.org/) is supposed to be an API browser, but I was not able to find the very basic objects, like `PlaneGeometry` or `SphereGeometry`. Is there any other place where to find an API?

Comment: The API changes A LOT anyway which I imagine is a reason why documentation is a problem, but I've always started from existing examples which are simple/easy to break down and moved on from there.

Comment: Just added some base description for all *Geometry - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/API-Reference

Comment: this is ridiculous for even simple stuff you have to go on scavenger hunt and if you are lucky you will find something that can be reverse engineered. Only to discover that this maybe outdated and won't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another place to browse the API is [here](http://www.staunsholm.dk/THREE/jsdoc/). I think both this and the one you referenced were generated before the recent name change for geometry objects. You could ask [staunsholm](https://github.com/staunsholm) to regenerate the API docs that he posted. Another, more official-looking place is [here](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/), but it still has quite a few "to-do's" in it.

I feel the same way about the lack of up-to-date documentation for THREE.js. If you want to apply some influence toward prioritizing this, you could reopen [this bugtracker issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/76) and comment on it. Or you could take it upon yourself :-) to maintain a frequently-updated THREE.js API reference, generated with jsdoc. Alternatively, you can dig through the source code and examples to find answers to your questions, and then update [the apparently official wiki pages](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/) with your discoveries.

Sorry this is not the ideal solution you were hoping for, but maybe it's the best available solution for now. The author of three.js [seems to feel](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/76) that the API needs to stabilize more before a documentation effort would be worthwhile for him.

Comment: about 1st link, i am under impression that directionalLight has property `position` and method `normalize()`, either it's of its own or inherited from somewhere, but i can't find it. Can you help or tell what is going on.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: Regarding the 1st link, the note at the bottom of the page says the doc was generated Jan 02 2013. If you follow the 3rd link, you'll find DirectionalLight with a `position` property, and an inheritance diagram. I don't see any `normalize()` method.

Comment: `directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();` something like this

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: In that case, it's not `directionalLight` that has a `normalize()` method, but rather `Vector3D` does. `position` is a `Vector3D`, as is the value returned by `position.set()`.

Answer (score 7):

**Latest official API is currently here**
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/

Answer (score 4):

three.js doc is in the examples. http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/

try them and look at the sources, they are quite clear. There is 112 of them and they are carefully maintained. It gives doc and test at the same time. There is no API documentation at the moment, and i dont think there will be in a near future.

It is more about. take an example close to what you want, and derive it.

Comment: Sadly the examples are quite complicated to start with. I would really appreciate to see, say, an example with a single rectangle with a texture on it. Moreover, the examples I opened lack comments, hence they are even less helpful.

Comment: The examples and API should be quite self descriptive. Albeit there are indeed some examples that are a bit convoluted. Try to focus on the easy ones first :)

Comment: In theory they are. But because of the lack of *really* simple examples, I cannot figure out the use of some parts of the API. For instance, in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919516/using-textures-in-three-js I tried to use a texture in the simplest possible way, and I thought I had everything right, but it turns out it does not work. It is hard for me to say what is different wrt to more complicated examples, where may other features are used.

Answer (score 3):

**Official API is here:**

Documentation: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/48/index.html

Full Index: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/48/genindex.html

And is pretty detailed at present.

Comment: Thank you, all this documentation was not there when I first asked :-)

Comment: @Andrea, the second one is not there anymore, and the first one has a lot of "todo"s in it. (Which is not to say that it isn't the best three.js documentation available.)

Comment: P.S. I think the official URL is http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/latest/, which does currently redirect to the first URL given above, but may not always do so.

Comment: Looks like it's all we have, but it isn't as good as it could... If I wasn't clueless about it I'd help.

Comment: Currently it's http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/ , which redirects to the latest version-specific API (50 today). It is still lacking, though, and even the source code is missing comments...

Comment: At the very moment even the latest docs are outdated. The easiest way to "browse" the signatures etc. is with proper JavaScript IDE. [Eclipse's free JSDT](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/) should be able to make it browseable and auto-complete, thanks to standard way of using prototype in Three.js source code. Also I've tried with  WebStorm (warning! proprietary) and it seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

I have written a set of more than 60 introductory examples with detailed comments at

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/

These examples are meant to illustrate many of the basic features of Three.js, one at a time, and as the examples progress some build upon each other, some increase in complexity, and some incorporate additional Javascript libraries.

Hope this helps!

Comment: they're nice but I can't even right click and view source.  Maybe it's just my chrome browser.

Comment: If you can't view the source from the demo, try the link to the GitHub page, you can also browse the source code that way.

Answer (score 2):

There is algo a book published recently: [WebGL: Up and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024729.do?sortby=publicationDate), which is based on THREE.js, so you'll get complete understanding of how it works. I think it's a good place to start if you want to get overall knowledge of all THREE.js aspects and not just by scrutinizing separate examples.