# Using textures in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am starting with THREE.js, and I am trying to draw a rectangle with a texture on it, lit by a single source of light. I think this is as simple as it gets (HTML omitted for brevity):

```
function loadScene() {
    var world = document.getElementById('world'),
        WIDTH = 1200,
        HEIGHT = 500,
        VIEW_ANGLE = 45,
        ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
        NEAR = 0.1,
        FAR = 10000,

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(),
        camera = new THREE.Camera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR),
        scene = new THREE.Scene(),
        texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate.gif'),
        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture}),
        // material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xCC0000});
        geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100),
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material),
        pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);

    camera.position.z = 200;    
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    scene.addChild(mesh);
    world.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    pointLight.position.x = 50;
    pointLight.position.y = 50;
    pointLight.position.z = 130;
    scene.addLight(pointLight); 
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

The problem is, I cannot see anything. If I change the material and use the commented one, a square appears as I would expect. Note that

- The texture is 256x256, so its sides are power of two
- The function is actually called when the body is loaded; indeed it works with a different material.
- It does not work even if I serve the file from a webserver, so it is not an issue of cross-domain policy not allowing to load the image.

What I am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

By the time the image is loaded, the renderer has already drawn the scene, hence it is too late. The solution is to change

```
texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate.gif'),
```

into

```
texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate.gif', {}, function() {
    renderer.render(scene);
}),
```

Comment: These days, the answer is to ditch `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture` (which is deprecated) and use `THREE.TextureLoader.load` instead. `ImageUtils` didn't work at all for me, but `TextureLoader` worked perfectly the first time I tried it. Docs: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/loaders/TextureLoader

Answer (score 28):

Andrea solution is absolutely right, I will just write another implementation based on the same idea.
If you took a look at the THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture() [source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/ImageUtils.js) you will find it uses the javascript Image object. The $(window).load event is fired after all Images are loaded ! so at that event we can render our scene with the textures already loaded...

- CoffeeScript

  ```
  $(document).ready ->

      material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("crate.gif"))

      sphere   = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings), material)

      $(window).load ->
          renderer.render scene, camera
  ```
- JavaScript

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("crate.gif") });

      sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, rings), material);

      $(window).load(function() {
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
      });
  });
  ```

Thanks...

Answer (score 24):

In version r75 of three.js, you should use:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load('texture.png', function ( texture ) {
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1000, 20, 20);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture, overdraw: 0.5});
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
});
```

Comment: Great Answer! I'm guessing the API changed since the original answer. Your answer is functional! Many Thanks!

Comment: you should've probably provided which revision of three.js did you refer to as _latest_.

Answer (score 6):

In version r82 of Three.js [TextureLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader) is the object to use for loading a texture.

### Loading one texture ([source code](https://gist.github.com/marcopompili/0251e1a6e86bfeefd5f740bcca7fa084), [demo](http://bl.ocks.org/marcopompili/0251e1a6e86bfeefd5f740bcca7fa084))

Extract ([test.js](https://gist.github.com/marcopompili/0251e1a6e86bfeefd5f740bcca7fa084#file-test-js)):

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var ratio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1, 50);

var renderer = ...

[...]

/**
 * Will be called when load completes.
 * The argument will be the loaded texture.
 */
var onLoad = function (texture) {
  var objGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);
  var objMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: texture,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading
  });

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(objGeometry, objMaterial);

  scene.add(mesh);

  var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.010;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.010;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };

  render();
}

// Function called when download progresses
var onProgress = function (xhr) {
  console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
};

// Function called when download errors
var onError = function (xhr) {
  console.log('An error happened');
};

var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load('texture.jpg', onLoad, onProgress, onError);
```

### Loading multiple textures ([source code](https://gist.github.com/marcopompili/082a159fcfc7c349771d10cbe991fb5d), [demo](http://bl.ocks.org/marcopompili/082a159fcfc7c349771d10cbe991fb5d))

In this example the textures are loaded inside the constructor of the mesh, multiple texture are loaded using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Extract ([Globe.js](https://gist.github.com/marcopompili/082a159fcfc7c349771d10cbe991fb5d#file-globe-js)):

Create a new container using `Object3D` for having two meshes in the same container:

```
var Globe = function (radius, segments) {

  THREE.Object3D.call(this);

  this.name = "Globe";

  var that = this;

  // instantiate a loader
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
```

A map called `textures` where every object contains the `url` of a texture file and `val` for storing the value of a Three.js [texture](https://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Textures/Texture) object.

```
  // earth textures
  var textures = {
    'map': {
      url: 'relief.jpg',
      val: undefined
    },
    'bumpMap': {
      url: 'elev_bump_4k.jpg',
      val: undefined
    },
    'specularMap': {
      url: 'wateretopo.png',
      val: undefined
    }
  };
```

The array of promises, for each object in the map called `textures` push a new Promise in the array `texturePromises`, every Promise will call `loader.load`. If the value of `entry.val` is a valid `THREE.Texture` object, then resolve the promise.

```
  var texturePromises = [], path = './';

  for (var key in textures) {
    texturePromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var entry = textures[key]
      var url = path + entry.url

      loader.load(url,
        texture => {
          entry.val = texture;
          if (entry.val instanceof THREE.Texture) resolve(entry);
        },
        xhr => {
          console.log(url + ' ' + (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) +
            '% loaded');
        },
        xhr => {
          reject(new Error(xhr +
            'An error occurred loading while loading: ' +
            entry.url));
        }
      );
    }));
  }
```

`Promise.all` takes the promise array `texturePromises` as argument. Doing so makes the browser wait for all the promises to resolve, when they do we can load the geometry and the material.

```
  // load the geometry and the textures
  Promise.all(texturePromises).then(loadedTextures => {

    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, segments);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: textures.map.val,
      bumpMap: textures.bumpMap.val,
      bumpScale: 0.005,
      specularMap: textures.specularMap.val,
      specular: new THREE.Color('grey')
    });

    var earth = that.earth = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    that.add(earth);
  });
```

For the cloud sphere only one texture is necessary:

```
  // clouds
  loader.load('n_amer_clouds.png', map => {
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius + .05, segments, segments);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: map,
      transparent: true
    });

    var clouds = that.clouds = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    that.add(clouds);
  });
}

Globe.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Object3D.prototype);
Globe.prototype.constructor = Globe;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Without Error Handeling**

```
//Load background texture
 new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1205301/pexels-photo-1205301.jpeg' , function(texture)
            {
             scene.background = texture;  
            });
```

**With Error Handling**

```
// Function called when download progresses
var onProgress = function (xhr) {
  console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
};

// Function called when download errors
var onError = function (error) {
  console.log('An error happened'+error);
};

//Function  called when load completes.
var onLoad = function (texture) {
  var objGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30, 30, 30);
  var objMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: texture,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading
  });

  var boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(objGeometry, objMaterial);
  scene.add(boxMesh);

  var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    boxMesh.rotation.x += 0.010;
    boxMesh.rotation.y += 0.010;
      sphereMesh.rotation.y += 0.1;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };

  render();
}


//LOAD TEXTURE and on completion apply it on box
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/97/The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg/1920px-The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg', 
                onLoad, 
                onProgress, 
                onError);
```

**Result:**

[image]

https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/jpGLpq/

Answer (score 0):

Use TextureLoader to load a image as texture and then simply apply that texture to scene background.

```
 new THREE.TextureLoader();
     loader.load('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1205301/pexels-photo-1205301.jpeg' , function(texture)
                {
                 scene.background = texture;  
                });
```

Result:

https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/jpGLpq?editors=0011

See the Pen [Flat Earth Three.JS](https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu/pen/jpGLpq/) by Hitesh  Sahu ([@hiteshsahu](https://codepen.io/hiteshsahu)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).