# How to apply a texture to THREE.ExtrudeGeometry?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

```
var arcShape = new THREE.Shape();
arcShape.moveTo( 50, 10 );
arcShape.absarc( 10, 10, 40, 0, Math.PI*2, false );

var map1 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'moon.jpg' );
var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( arcShape, extrudeSettings );
var new3D = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: map1 } ) );
new3D.receiveShadow = true;
obj3Dmassive.add( new3D );
```

Texture (512x512): http://f3.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhNj.png

Result: http://f3.s.qip.ru/cMfvUhNh.png

How to fill a texture figure?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919516/using-textures-in-three-js

Comment: @RachelGallen, ...THREE.ExtrudeGeometry...............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Answer outdated. See [Extruding multiple polygons with multiple holes and texturing the combined shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124691/extruding-multiple-polygons-with-multiple-holes-and-texturing-the-combined-shape) instead.

---

You are lucky. What you are trying to do has been done in the following example:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_uvs2.html

You have to specify your own UV generator function. This example shows you how to do that.

Remember, this is just an example. It may not be correct -- or easy to implement in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If you just have a straight extrusion path, you can apply textures to extruded shapes without the need for a custom UV generator. e.g.

```
var extrudeSettings = {
                bevelEnabled: false, 
                steps: 1,
                amount: 20, //extrusion depth, don't define an extrudePath
                material:0, //material index of the front and back face
                extrudeMaterial : 1 //material index of the side faces            
            };

var geometry = shape.extrude(extrudeSettings);

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, 
    new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial([materialFace, materialSide]));
```

This is handy for cookie-cutter type shapes.