# Materials loaded event with JSONLoader

Tags: three.js

I would like to detect when JSONLoader loaded the model and all of its UV textures.
I tried to use the LoadingMonitor, but it was not useful. It didn't log "Loaded" message.
I don't know why. I did everything according to the example. What did I wrong?

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager(function() {
  console.log("Loaded");
});
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(manager);
loader.load("model.js", function(geometry, materials) { 
  ...
});
```

Otherwise can it fire when textures are loaded? Or is it detectable?

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712047/how-to-wait-for-textures-to-finish-loading-from-json-model-in-three-js

Comment: I don't want to modify the source code of JSONLoader for now.

Comment: As @mrdoob stated in his answer in the above link, this is not yet sorted out. ( r.64 ) Can you remove the textures from the JSON file and load them manually as a work-around?

Comment: Yes, it's an option, if there's nothing else.