# Three.js create texture from image file

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I'm having some trouble creating a texture from an image file in Three.js.  I have a function to create a mesh that looks like this:

```
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = imageFile;
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(image);
    var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
    mat.map = texture;

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20), mat);
    var plane = mesh;
    plane.position.x = 0;
    scene.add(plane);
```

However, my texture renders black and the image doesn't seem to render properly.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919516/using-textures-in-three-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to use an image as a texture is to load it using `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(url, mapping, onLoad, onError)`, here is an example:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1, 1, 1 ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/my-image.jpg') })
);
```

The `THREE.Texture` constructor does accept an image as its first parameter, I think the problem you are encountering is because you aren't waiting for the image to complete loading. Using `ImageUtils` you can avoid having to dealing with callbacks.

Comment: So how is this answer different than the given comment?

Comment: `ImageUtils.loadTexture` is deprecated, so this answer isn't relevant anymore