# Not able to load Image texture in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is my code -

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// adding a camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
//camera.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);


// setting up the renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(renderW, renderH);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);




// creating the panorama

// panoramas image
var panoramasArray = ["01.jpg"];



// creation of a big sphere geometry
// default segments of sphere w 8 h 6
var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(400,100,40);
sphere.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(-1, 1, 1));

// creation of the sphere material
//var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x0000FF});
sphereMaterial.map =THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(panoramasArray[1])

// geometry + material = mesh (actual object)
sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere, sphereMaterial);
scene.add(sphereMesh);

camera.position.z = 900;

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I am running this on localhost apache server, but nothing visible in the browser. A black screen.

However, when I do this -

```
function render()
{   
requestAnimationFrame(render);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Everything works fine then ! I tried adding a callback on ImageUtils.Load but still nothing is rendered on screen until I put in an animation loop. I have been scratching my head since days now. Please explain n help. I dont want to put the animation frame just to display the image texture.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using textures in THREE.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919516/using-textures-in-three-js)

Answer (score 0):

Loading a texture is done via an asynchronous `XMLHTTPRequest`. When the image is loaded after few hundred of milliseconds, the main script has executed the `render` call long time ago.

You have to move `renderer.render(scene,camera)` to the loader `onLoad` callback which is its third parameter :

```
THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( URL, mapping, function(){
      renderer.render(scene,camera);
});
```

see the [doc](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras/ImageUtils)

Comment: You are not passing in the proper args to `loadTexture()`.

Comment: i considered checking the doc few seconds, i should have :). Edited