# How to use a number of pictures to form a graphic in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to use **three.js** to generate a shape(maybe some word) composed of some pictures like that:

[image]

I think what i have to do is get some points which form a shape, then put the picture to these points. I have searched for something information , but i still have no idea how can i get these points because the shape maybe irregular. Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you have two ways to proceed here:

1. You can use a modeling software like Blender to first generate the shape along with the pictures, and then export the JSON (refer [this](https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2015/07/27/importing-blender-modelized-mesh-in-threejs.html) for how to setup the threejs json exporter in blender ) and then use the JSON loader to load that JSON.
2. The other way is that you create simple geometries of your requried shape using the ones threejs provides like box, circle, etc ( refer [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=geometry) ) and then add textures to it as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919516/using-textures-in-three-js) .

---

Hope one of these solutions is what you're looking for.

Comment: First way, picture should be added dynamically, so can't be inited using json file. In second way, my shape is irregularly and can't be created using which threejs provided.

Comment: So you want the shape to be according to what the user wants, dynamically right? Check out this example (https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Voxel-Painter.html) Are you looking for something along that line?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the canvas to plot the 3d positions of each photo.

I created a fiddle here with text:

https://jsfiddle.net/2qu6m4h3/

And one with random shapes:

https://jsfiddle.net/d2th9ekb/

It creates a canvas element to draw text to. It interrogates the canvas for pixel positions. Those positions are then sent to a function which places cubes in 3d. Rather than place cubes you could place sprite objects which display each one of your photos. Use the scale property to give yourself more room between positions.

Here's the code:

```
/*
Start Setup text canvas and tools
*/
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width  = 400;
ctx.canvas.height = 200;
function createTextSourceCanvas(text,src) {
    src.font = '50pt Times';
    src.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
    src.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    src.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
    src.textAlign = "center";
    src.textBaseline = "middle";
    src.fillText(text, canvas.width /2, canvas.height /2);
}
function examineText(src, fi){
    var positiveResults = [];
    var width = src.canvas.width;
  var height = src.canvas.height;
  var imgData = src.getImageData(0, 0,width, height);
    for(var x = 0; x < width; x+=fi){
   for(var y = 0; y < height; y+=fi  ){
    var pixel = getPixelXY(imgData, x, y)
    if(pixel[0] == 0 && pixel[1] == 255 && pixel[2] == 0){
        continue;
    }
    positiveResults.push([x,y]);
   }
  }
  return positiveResults;
}
function getPixel(imgData, index) {
  var i = index*4, d = imgData.data;
  return [d[i],d[i+1],d[i+2],d[i+3]]
}
function getPixelXY(imgData, x, y) {
  return getPixel(imgData, y*imgData.width+x);
}
/*
End Setup text canvas and tools
*/

/*
Start Setup Threejs canvas and tools
*/
var scene;
var renderer;
var camera;
var cube;
var controls;
function init3d(){
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
  var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize (width, height);
    document.body.appendChild (renderer.domElement);
  scene = new THREE.Scene()
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (45, width/height, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.y = 160;
    camera.position.z = 400;
    camera.lookAt (new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls (camera, renderer.domElement);
    var gridXZ = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 10);
    scene.add(gridXZ);
    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight (0xffffff);
    pointLight.position.set (0,300,200);
    scene.add (pointLight);
    window.addEventListener ('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}
function onWindowResize (){
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
function animate(){
    controls.update();
  requestAnimationFrame ( animate );  
    renderer.render (scene, camera);
}
/*
End Setup Threejs canvas and tools
*/

/*
Start create 3d from text examination
*/
function create3dProjectionText(scene, positions, wExtent, hExtent, scale){
    if(scale == undefined){
        scale = 1;
  }
  var group = new THREE.Object3D();

  var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry (2,2,2);
    var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial ({color: 0xFFFFFF});

  for(var i in positions){
        cube = new THREE.Mesh (cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
      cube.position.set (positions[i][0]*scale - (wExtent*scale/2), positions[i][1]*scale -(hExtent*scale/2), 0);
      group.add (cube);
  }
  group.rotateX( -Math.PI  );
  scene.add(group);
}
/*
End create 3d from text examination
*/
//initialize the 3d space
init3d();
//initialize the text canvas
createTextSourceCanvas("Hello World", ctx);
//
create3dProjectionText(scene, examineText(ctx ,4), ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height, 1.5);
animate();
```